# PlaceAutoCompleteFragment in a Fragment Unable to Start Activity

Tags: kotlin, fragment, google-places-api

I have implemented an `AutoCompleteFragment` with Google Places API in an Activity, but when I try to implement it in a fragment returns Unable to start activity error.

The fragment is in a `MainActivity` with `DrawerMenu`

LogCat:

```
2020-06-23 20:19:14.240 5546-5546/com.aitorramos.dogtravel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aitorramos.dogtravel, PID: 5546
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aitorramos.dogtravel/com.aitorramos.dogtravel.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.aitorramos.dogtravel.Fragments.SearchFragment.setupAutoComplete(SearchFragment.kt:59)
    at com.aitorramos.dogtravel.Fragments.SearchFragment.onCreateView(SearchFragment.kt:45)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

SearchFragment.kt:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)

        setupAutoComplete(R.id.gCityFrom, 0)

        return view
    }

    private fun setupAutoComplete(fragment: Int, flag: Int){

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(requireContext(), apiKey)
        }
        
        //Return null
        val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager!!.findFragmentById(fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment?

        //error here
        autocompleteFragment!!.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)) 
.....
```

fragment_search.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gCityFrom"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager!!.findFragmentById(R.id.gCityFrom) as AutocompleteSupportFragment?
```

instead of

```
val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager!!.findFragmentById(fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment?
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using

```
val autocompleteFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment?
```